# How dangerous is soldering lead gas?

Tags: soldering, solder-paste

I get exposed to the gas of solder lead and/or flux all the time when I solder. How dangerous is it? Should I avoid it at all costs or it's not of a big deal as people think?

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/are-solder-fumes-bad-for-me

Comment: It's worth noting that the fumes from soldering are 100% from the flux unless you're using a *very* strange solder alloy. There is zero lead in the fumes.

Comment: It is unhealthy and can cause allergy or asthma problems. If you solder frequently you should invest in a good fume extractor.